# python ctypes can't see symbol in shared library

Tags: shared-libraries, ctypes

I can see a symbol `fact` in a shared library:

```
> nm -D libtest.so
                 w __cxa_finalize
000000000000111a T fact
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
```

but when I do

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> lib = ctypes.CDLL('./libtest.so')
>>> lib.fact
```

I get

```
AttributeError: ./libtest.so: undefined symbol: fact
```

Here's the content of my `test.c` file:

```
int fact(int n);
int fact(int n) {
  if (n <= 0)
    return 1;
  return n*fact(n-1);
}
```

I compile the shared library using

```
> gcc -c -fPIC test.c -o test.o
> gcc -shared -o libtest.so test.o
```

I'm stumped. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly where your problem lies since it works fine for me :-)

Suggest you try the steps in the following transcript *exactly* to see if there's an issue (`pax$` is my prompt, not part of the commands, and you'll see I'm *explicitly* using `./` for files to ensure *no* possibility that it will use files elsewhere in your various search paths):

```
pax$ cat ./test.c
int fact(int n) { return (n <= 0) ? 1 : n * fact(n-1); }

pax$ gcc -c -fPIC ./test.c -o ./test.o
pax$ gcc -shared -o ./libtest.so ./test.o
pax$ nm -D ./libtest.so
0000000000201028 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000201028 D _edata
0000000000201030 B _end
0000000000000680 T fact
00000000000006ac T _fini
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000528 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses

pax$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import ctypes
>>> lib = ctypes.CDLL('./libtest.so') ; lib
<CDLL './libtest.so', handle 1131fe0 at 0x7fd4c53cf978>

>>> lib.fact
<_FuncPtr object at 0x7fd4c550de58>

>>> lib.fact(6)
720
```

Comment: You were right.  Some other library was being brought in.  Changing names containing `test` to `fact` took care of the problem.  Thanks.